# Incorrectly executed script for the selection of IP addresses

Tags: php, pdo

I wrote a small script to remove unwanted IP addresses from the list, but script still displays IP addresses from `$ip_list`, although in condition `if` nothing happens

```
$ip_list = array("37.13.","217.118.","207.46.");
$top = $pdo->prepare('SELECT DISTINCT ip FROM logs ORDER BY ip DESC');
$top->execute();
while ($toppost = $top->fetch(PDO::FETCH_LAZY)){
    $array[] = $toppost->ip;
}



for ($i = 0; $i <= count($ip_list); $i++){
    for ($a = 0; $a <= count($array); $a++){
        $b = explode(".", $array[$a]);
        $n = $b[0].".".$b[1].".";
            if ($ip_list[$i] == $n){        

            }
            else{
                echo $n."<br/>";
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: what you trying to do ?

Comment: unwanted ip means what you mean ?

Comment: "in condition `if` nothing happens", because you have there no code? Where is the code responsible for "removing"?

Comment: @MichałSznurawa, namely, there is no code, because I don't need an IP address that begins "37.13.", "217,118.", "207.46."

Comment: Why are you impload your $array[$a] to implode it just after using concatenation ?

Comment: Your goal is to print all addresses fetched from db, as long as they don't match patterns from `$ip_list`, right?

Comment: @MichałSznurawa, I need to print all IP-addresses from database, except those that start with `$ip_list`

Comment: Solution provided by Sofiene DJEBALI should work for you. Your code is wrong, and it not only prints unwanted ips, but it prints everything else multpile (3 I recon) times. And unwanted ips are printed one time less (2). This is because you are printing (or not) after every comparison with each black listed element, and single IP from doesn't match just one item from $ip_list...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work :

**PHP**

```
$ip_list = array("37.13.","217.118.","207.46.");
$top = $pdo->prepare('SELECT DISTINCT ip FROM logs ORDER BY ip DESC');
$top->execute();
while ($toppost = $top->fetch(PDO::FETCH_LAZY)){
    $b = explode(".", $toppost->ip);
    $formated_ip = $b[0].".".$b[1].".";
    if (in_array($formated_ip, $ip_list)) {
        //IP From database in $ip_list array    
    } else {
        echo $formated_ip . "<br/>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this use `unset()`

```
for ($a = 0; $a <= count($array); $a++)
{


    $b = explode(".", $array[$a]);

    $n = $b[0].".".$b[1].".";


        if (in_array($n,$ip_list))
        {        
                unset($array[$a]);
        }
        else
        {
            echo $n."<br/>";
        }
   }
```

Comment: and, your first example doesn't correct to work, but second perfect work